# performSelector:onThread: when the target thread is blocked

Tags: cocoa

Yes, I'm being lazy.

What happens when I call `performSelector:onThread:...` and pass in a thread that's currently blocked (on synchronous I/O, for instance)? Does the selector just get queued to be executed later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. I'm pretty sure it gets added to the thread's runloop so it will be performed on the next iteration.